# For spaces X and Y , find their intersection X⋂Y and hence show that X⋂Y is a 1-dimensional subspace of R 4.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $$X=\{(t,2t−s,s,3s−t) \mid s,t \in R\},$$ $$Y=\{(2q−p,p−q,3p−q,5q) \mid p,q \in R\}$$ with both $X$ and $Y$ subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Write down a basis for space $X$ and a basis for space $Y$. Hence, or otherwise, find a basis for $X + Y$.

Comment: Please learn to format your code in LaTeX to make it more readable and actually encourage others to want to answer your question.

Comment: Note that each subspace has "two parametres", hence, they are kind of telling that they are subspaces of dimension two. Try set $(s,t) = (0,1),(1,0)$ and similarly for $(p,q)$ and check that the vectors obtained in this way are a basis for each subspace. I don't understand the last part.

Comment: Thank you for your input NoseKnowsAll, it really helped answer my question.